# How to pass intent to another intent

Tags: java, android

hey guys im trying to create a quiz, but im having trouble in the intent,after the user will clicked the button, it will automatically intent to another activity.. how can i do that?

please help guys...thanks in advance..

this is the code:

```
if(btn1.isClickable())
    {
        img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.check);

        img2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);

        img3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        img3.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Scorecount++;
                Intent i = getIntent();
                startActivity(i);
                Scorecount = i.getIntExtra("score",0);

            }
        });

    }
    else if (btn2.isClickable())
    {
        img2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);

        img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);

        img3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        img3.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
    }
    else if (btn3.isClickable())
    {
        img3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        img3.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);

        img2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        img2.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);

        img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
    }
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = getIntent();
            startActivity(i);
            Scorecount = i.getIntExtra("score",0);

        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = getIntent();
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = getIntent();
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

first activity

```
Intent i= new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,
                    NextActivity.class);

            i.putExtra("quiz", array[0]);
            i.putExtra("pass_value","Pass value");
            startActivity(i);
```

second activity

```
String getvalue= getIntent().getSerializableExtra("pass_value").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you want, but you can add one intent to another one because intent implements parceable.You can do:

```
intent.putExtra("INTENT_KEY", someOtherIntent);
```

and then:

```
intent = getIntent();
Intent someOtherIntent = (Intent)intent.getParcelableExtra("INTENT_KEY");
```

Does it help?

P.S. Your code is very strange... (I mean wrong and senseless sometimes)

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass the parameters you create new intent and put a parameter map:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivityClassName.class);
myIntent.putExtra("firstKeyName","FirstKeyValue");
myIntent.putExtra("secondKeyName","SecondKeyValue");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

In order to get the parameters values you must call the `get[type]Extra()` on the same intent:

```
Intent myIntent= getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
String firstKeyName = intent.getStringExtra("firstKeyName"); // will return "FirstKeyValue"
String firstKeyName = intent.getStringExtra("firstKeyName"); // will return "SecondKeyValue"
```

If your parameters are ints you would use `getIntExtra()` instead etc. 
Now you can use your parameters like you normally would.